# Are there any ductless mini split systems that can use standard HVAC control wiring cables

Tags: wiring, hvac, air-conditioning, mini-split

I have a worn out 1990's quad mini-split system that use a separate class 2 (power limited) 24v control cable 18/5 to each indoor unit. The power for the indoor and outdoor units comes from 2 separate breakers in the same panelboard, and the indoor units are wired 12/2 plus ground, there are no surplus conductors. Re-wiring would require opening around 200 feet of skim coat plaster and is not a viable proposal due to cost schedule and intrusion. See details far below.

Apart from having bamboozled UL to classify the power feed to the indoor units as internal to the installed device so that the HVAC installer doesn't need a licensed electrician, and avoided the need to maintain separation for the control cable by multiplexing the control signaling onto a single wire in the power cable, there isn't a significant change and I don't see an insurmountable obstacle. That the control wire is normally bundled in the power cable makes in unclear if the signal circuit has the required isolation to use low voltage cable already or if it needs some kind of isolator module. I haven't run into any manufacturer's installation literature that deviates from the first version someone translated that's so busy gushing about not needing a separate control cable it doesn't address installations where that's what's needed. I've seen one site where someone talked about an interface for use with some Mitsubishi models for what seemed to be this purpose, but I can't find it anymore among all the jubilant announcements for interface modules that adapt a 24v thermostat (e.g. Nest) to specific indoor units, which is a different problem.

For the existing installation, the 4 indoor units receive 240vac power from a circuit breaker wired 12/2 with ground that goes to a pull box where the 12/2 + ground cables for the 4 individual units are joined together. The outdoor condenser is powered at 240VAC from a different circuit breaker cabled 10/3 plus ground, the neutral is not used and is capped at the condenser. The condenser is a convention design with 4 compressors and 4 independent refrigerant circuits. The only components the 4 subsystems share are the condenser fan and the 24v control transformer.

Finally, I appreciate that there are a variety of strongly held beliefs about the re-use of copper refrigerant tubing for R410a. This is also a constraint, but for the purpose of this question please assume that the world has enough acetone, circulating pumps, filter media and patience to remove every trace of synthetic alkylbenzene oil (not MO) so that re-using the electrical cables is the only question that needs to be addressed at this time.

Comment: What is your question? Are you planning to replace this 90s heat pump? You seem to be leaping in with all the details, but not giving us the basics.

Comment: Yes, the reason I want to know if there are any mini-splits that can be used to replace without rewiring is because the system needs to be replaced or rebuilt. I've kept it going for 30y but now its time for condenser and evaporator coils, drip pans, blower bearings and on and on. It would a lot less hours to replace than rebuild as long as it can be done without rewiring.

Comment: I take it by "control cable" you mean the cable between the interior and exterior units, correct?

Comment: I would not reuse 30 year old "refrigerant tubing". Today's mini-splits get their power and control signals from the outdoor unit.  You have more than one problem to consider.

Comment: By refrigerant tubing I mean the copper tubing that the refrigerant flows inside.  The inside doesn't age in use and oil is very soluble in acetone which leaves no residue. What you'd do is your choice. I don't need 150 hours of extra work. The outdoor unit is just a fused junction box so the power conductors can be smaller/cheaper, no relay, no variable speed motor drive. The control wire is generically a single wire serial bus referenced to the grounded conductor. Either end point can signal, some systems only signal from the inside, some signal from the outside for diagnostic on/off inside.

Comment: @3ɸEE by control cable I mean the conductors used for signaling as distinct from the conductors used to deliver energy. The prevalent mini-split cable places a single insulated signal conductor and insulated power conductors within a single jacket as a cable assembly. Some designs use one of the ungrounded conductors as the reference for the signal, others use the grounded conductor (aka neutral) or the (equipment) grounding (aka safety ground) conductor. The signal conductor is usually the same gauge as the power conductors to safely accommodate color-blind and in-duh-vi-du-al installers.